# vue-i18n date localization not localizing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, internationalization, vue-i18n

I have an app that's localized with vue-i18n. All the strings are saved in a JSON file and the translation works. Now I need to add a datetime localization [as seen here](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/datetime.html) but the module doesn't pick up my configuration and I get warnings in the console about "Fall back to 'en-US' datetime formats from 'en datetime formats."

config

```js
import messages from './messages.json'
const dateTimeFormats = {
  'en-US': {
    short: {
      year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric'
    }
  }
}

const i18n = new VueI18n({
  locale: 'en',
  messages,
  dateTimeFormats
})
```

template

```html
<b-col cols="7" lg="12"><p class="margin-0">{{ $d(new Date(), 'short') }}</p></b-col>
```

I've tried explicitly setting `{{ $d(new Date(), 'short', 'en-US') }}`, I've tried only passing the `dateTimeFormats` I keep getting the same warning and nothing prints in my markup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything works like expected. Take a look on the snippet bellow.
Maybe your problem come from elsewhere?

```js
const dateTimeFormats = {
  'en-US': {
    short: {
      year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric'
    }
  }
}
const messages = {
  'en-US': {
    foo: 'bar'
  }
}

const i18n = new VueI18n({
  locale: 'en',
  messages,
  dateTimeFormats
})

new Vue({
  i18n
}).$mount("#app");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-i18n/8.14.0/vue-i18n.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{ $d(new Date(), 'short') }}</p>
  <p>{{ $t('foo') }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you able to use both the `dateTimeFormats` and a message object for string translations?